# Удаление переноса строки из текста

Tags: java, файлы, split

Есть файл с текстом типа

`"
А1,
Б2,
В3,
...
"`

Читаю файл вот так:

```
String text = "";
try {
 FileReader fr = new FileReader("file.txt");
 int c;
 while((c = fr.read())> 0){
  text = text.concat(String.valueOf((char)c));
 }

} catch (Exception ex) {
 ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Переменная `text` получается многострочной и я не могу её нормально обработать.
Мне нужно разделить её на строки поменьше и поместить их в массив, пытался вот так:

```
String[] BukviArray = text.replace("\n","").split(", ");
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как убрать все переносы строк из `text`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
text.replaceAll("\n","");
```

Или если вам надо только разделить, то так:

```java
text.split(",\n");
```